# On which site should I post this question about my parents' behavior?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to know about a behavior which my parent did to me.

Is there a site where I can ask questions about that?

Comment: We have a site about [Parenting](http://parenting.stackexchange.com), where occasionally children ask questions as well. But without knowing your exact question, it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess when you say *behavior which my parent did to me*, you are asking this from a parenting point of view (why they treated you like this or rules they enforced, etc.).

There is a site that allows that type of questions, it is called [Parenting](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/). There are [some](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/27160) [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/22407) asked by teens about how to handle their parents behavior or decisions.

Make sure though that the exact question you want to ask is on-topic according to the [help center](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).